# Help find an old song in Spanish

Tags: letras-de-canciones

A lot of years ago I heard a song in Spanish, but nowdaays I do not remember its name. I only remember some phrase (pronunciation, not spelling), [here it is](https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru#view=home&op=translate&sl=es&tl=ru&text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%20%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D1%91%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE). If you know Spanish and or have ever heard something like that I would be glad to accept your help. Thanks!

Comment: I seriously doubt that this question is on-topic here, as it does not have to do with the Spanish Language itself, though indeed knowing Spanish may help in finding your song. The pronunciation seems to be "soy un hombre muy..." but I cannot imagine what the last word could be.

Comment: You can try in [musicfans.se], they accept questions about song identification

Answer (score 1):

Listening to your sentence, it seems to say "Soy un hombre muy honrado" (*I am a very honest man*), so the song you are looking for might be [La canción del mariachi](https://youtu.be/gXM8LjS-AOg) by Antonio Banderas and Los Lobos.